# Wordpress custom posts and permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post type called "menu" with the following categories

- hotboxes
- salads
- soups
- wraps

Code:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'menutype',
    array("menu"),
    array(
        "hierarchical" => true, 
        "label" => "Menu Categories", 
        "singular_label" => "Menu Category", 
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'menu/type', 'hierarchical'=>'true'), 
        "show_ui"=>"radio", // used a plugin
        "query_var" => true
    )
);
```

Right now if I want to say, show all my "hotboxes" it goes to

```
http://www.mysite.com/menu/type/hotboxes
```

But if it shows an *individual* hotbox it just goes to

```
http://www.mysite.com/menu/hotbox-single-item
```

Is there a way to rewrite the url so it says

```
http://www.mysite.com/menu/type/hotbox/hotbox-single-item
```

The ideal format I am looking for is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/custom_post_type/custom_taxonomy/post_name
```

EDIT: I managed to get the link **looking** like the way I wanted by doing:

```
function menu_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {

        $post = get_post($id);

        if ( $post->post_type != 'menu')
        {
            return $post_link;  
        }

        if( $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'menutype' ) ) {
            $custom_taxonomy = $terms[0]->slug;
            $post_link = str_replace('menu', 'menu/'.$custom_taxonomy, $post_link);
        }


        return $post_link;

    }
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'menu_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

Note: My custom post type is called "menu" and my custom taxonomy is called "menutype".

This now creates the permalink I want:

http://www.mysite.com/custom_post_type/custom_taxonomy/post_name

However it generates a 404 error even after flushing my rewrite rules (Settings > Permalinks > save)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        '(.+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'    =>  'index.php?post_type='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&custom_taxonomy='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&post_name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

You may need to modify the regex, as regex isn't one of my strongpoints, and you'll need to swap out your taxonomy name in the URL. You may want to hardcode the custom post type too and adjust the rest accordingly to avoid clashes.